# Is there a way to adjust a "global equalizer"?

Tags: sound, equalizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any Sound enhancers/equalizer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer)

The other day, I plugged a poor quality set of speakers into my PC (running Ubuntu 10.04).

I would have liked to have made some adjustments to some sort of equalizer, but couldn't find anything that affected the whole PC.

Is there such a thing?